# How to jump previous or next position in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

I want to jump to the previous (or next) position in Sublime Text 2.

- `C-i`, `C-o` in vim.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> in Visual Studio.

How can I do it in Sublime?

Comment: I suspect that it's `Ctrl-I`/`Ctrl-O` if you activate vintage mode.

Comment: I activate vintage mode. but I can't. Do you mean activate VintageEx  mode? I'll try it.

Comment: I have added my simplest  and awsome answer just copy and paste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a plugin, described [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2738), that adds navigation history.

Copy the [Python script](https://github.com/optilude/SublimeTextMisc/blob/master/navigationHistory.py) in your `Packages` directory.

Then add these lines to your key bindings configuration file, to have Visual Studio like binding:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+minus"], "command": "navigation_history_back"},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+="], "command": "navigation_history_forward"}
```

Comment: Supposedly this feature is built-in to Sublime 3

Comment: In Sublime 3, no plugin is needed. Preferences->Key Bindings, add: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "jump_back" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+="], "command": "jump_forward" }`

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is asked long time back. But I will anyway answer for future reference.

This is already integrated in Sublime Text 3 now. Shortcut keys are,

Shift + Alt + Minus = Jump Back
Alt + Minus = Jump Forward.

This is discussed in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996878/how-to-jump-to-previous-and-last-cursor-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Actually Alt+Minus jumps back and Shift+Alt+Minus jumps forward.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best answer for Linux and Windows users.

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "jump_back" },
  { "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "jump_forward" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default key binding that is shipped with Sublime Text 3. You can check it with `Sublime Text` > `Key Bindings`:

```
[
    ...
    { "keys": ["ctrl+minus"], "command": "jump_back" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+minus"], "command": "jump_forward" },
    ...
]
```

You can certainly overwrite it. But if you don't, that's what you'll have. ^^